# How do I create an IBOutlet for a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I'm following a Swift+Xcode tutorial on Table Views and they first add a new TableView to a ViewController in their storyboard, then using the assistant editor drag from the TableView to the ViewController.swift to create an IBOutlet. Seen this work in multiple tutorials.

This does not work for me, however. The blue line is there when I right-click and drag from the TableView but there is no option to create an outlet when I release it in the ViewController.swift code. Works fine for other basic objects like buttons or labels.

I'm using Xcode 11 and Swift 5.1. The tutorial is probably using something a bit older.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Drag from the view controller to the table to set a link from the variable in the controller to the table. Drag from the table to the view controller to set the delegates.

Comment: you need to change the class of the storyboard VC from UIViewController to your subclass (ViewController?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the storyboard
2. Select the View Controller
3. Open the panel on the right and click on the 4th item
4. Change the class name to your controller (ViewController?)
5. Rebuild to be sure
6. Try linking again